# simple html table. logic not clear

Tags: html

[THE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yI2x.png)

hi guys . i faced some problems creating this table . i entered the following code which i thought was correct but it isn't .

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
TABLE DESIGN 2
</TITLE> 
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE BORDER="1" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="200" >
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="6" ALIGN="CENTER">A</TD>
<TD ROWSPAN="3" ALIGN="CENTER">B</TD>
<TD ROWSPAN="2" ALIGN="CENTER">C</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="2" ALIGN="CENTER">E</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="3" ALIGN="CENTER">F</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="2" ALIGN="CENTER">F</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Downvoted because you're not exactly clear on how you want it to display.  Please update the question.

Comment: hi. sorry but i didn't get you. can you make yourself more clear ?

Comment: I see the link now.  It was a little unclear at first.

Comment: it's ok. can you help me identify the problem  now?

Comment: Stand by - I think I might have something for you.

Comment: sure buddy. i am waiting

Comment: Please ***STOP SHOUTING AT US!*** Writing in ALL CAPS is annoying, because it's really hard to read, but it's also considered **shouting and yelling** at your audience, which is just plain rude and offensive - **don't do that** and fix your post ASAP - thank you

Comment: really sorry for that. i will make sure it does not happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using 6 rows to do your math, you needed to insert an additional blank row above your "E" cell.

```html
<TABLE BORDER="1" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="200">
  <TR>
    <TD ROWSPAN="6" ALIGN="CENTER">1</TD>
    <TD ROWSPAN="3" ALIGN="CENTER">1/2</TD>
    <TD ROWSPAN="2" ALIGN="CENTER">1/3</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD ROWSPAN="2" ALIGN="CENTER">1/3</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD ROWSPAN="3" ALIGN="CENTER">1/2</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD ROWSPAN="2" ALIGN="CENTER">1/3</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering. can you please let me know the reason behind adding <tr></tr>? it will be really helpful to me

Comment: @joeylang Sure - basically the way you're using rowspan, you're styling based on the position of 6 rows in this table to get even math. To achieve the effect, your three "1/3" cells need to each have 2 rows to themselves. Therefore, "1/3 cell one" takes up rows 1 & 2, "1/3 cell two" takes up rows 3 & 4, and "1/3 cell three" takes up rows 5 & 6. This was breaking because "1/3 cell two" was actually starting at row 2 before we inserted the blank second row, so it was trying to fit into the space of the cell above it. Now it begins on row 3, so the math works out. Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks a lot. and yes i got it